# Delete outliers found by IsolationForest with pandas drop rows

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I found outliers using `Isolation forest` and assigned them to variable `y_outliers`. How can I now delete rows with these values from pandas?

```
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
clf = IsolationForest(max_samples=100, contamination = 0.1, random_state=42)
clf.fit(X)
y_outliers = clf.predict(X)
```

What to do next? How to delete rows if `y_outliers` is an array with ones (inliers) and -1 (outliers)?
I try

```
for i in y_outliers:
    if i == -1:
        X.drop(X.index(i))
```

But got `TypeError: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable`

Also I tried

```
for i in X:
    print(i)
    if y_outliers.loc[i] == -1:
        X.drop(i)
```

but got

`'the label [f1] is not in the [index]'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. To do this the way you are trying to do is following:

```
for i in range(len(y_outliers)):
    if y_outliers[i] == -1:
        X.drop(i,inplace = True)
```

Another way to do this is:

```
import pandas as pd
isolationdata = pd.DataFrame({'dropIndex':y_outliers})
result = pd.merge(X, isolationdata, left_index=True, right_index=True)
result = result[result.dropIndex == 1]
```

Accept and upvote the solution if it works. I have tested both the codes and they work. If there is an error, you can comment it.